# Matplotlib: How to make a stacked plot of count of values in a Numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

Hey I have the following problem. I have a array like this:

```
 arr1=
[[4 4 4]
 [4 4 6]
 [4 3 4]
 [4 4 7]
 [4 4 3]
 [4 4 1]
 [3 4 7]
 [4 3 7]
 [4 4 5]
 [4 3 6]]
```

Now i want to get a stacked bar plot(histogram), that shows the number of different elements,, like this:

[image]

My frist approach was to bincount the elements, fill the arrays up, but then i dont know what to do.

```
arr2=
    [[0 0 0]
     [0 0 1]
     [0 0 0]
     [1 3 1]
     [9 7 2]
     [0 0 1]
     [0 0 2]
     [0 0 3]]
```

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: @Varlor: Always useful to give a MWE. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the output

[image]

and the code to generate the same

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = np.array([[4, 4, 4],
 [4, 4, 6],
 [4, 3, 4],
 [4, 4, 7],
 [4, 4, 3],
 [4, 4, 1],
 [3, 4, 7],
 [4, 3, 7],
 [4, 4, 5],
 [4, 3, 6]])

columns = ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
out = {}
for column in columns:
    out[column] = pd.value_counts(df[column])

uniq_df = pd.DataFrame(out).fillna(0)

uniq_df.T.plot(kind="bar", stacked=True)
```

Comment: Also, `import pandas as pd` :)

Comment: @DavidG : Thanks. Corrected.

Comment: Is it possible to change the position of the legend?

Comment: Ok i will search for it. Do you know how i could save that plot? If i try to save it, it always saves a matplot plot

Comment: Is it possible to add a number to legend, althoug it do not appear in data, like the number "2", so that the colormap is the same to data which include th enumber 2 ?

Answer (score 2):

Adding an Altair based answer as well.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from altair import *
data = np.array([[4, 4, 4],
 [4, 4, 6],
 [4, 3, 4],
 [4, 4, 7],
 [4, 4, 3],
 [4, 4, 1],
 [3, 4, 7],
 [4, 3, 7],
 [4, 4, 5],
 [4, 3, 6]])

columns = ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
df = df.T.stack().reset_index(level=[0,1])
df.columns = ['Col','RowNum','Value']
Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(y='count(*)', x='Col:N', color='Value:N')
```

[image]

Comment: Is t possible to make the bars in this altair based approach wider? :)

Comment: It also says that "Chart" in the last line in your code is not defined and not a module of pandas

Comment: It's from altair. You'd need to install altair and then do: from altair import *

Comment: hmm ok, i installed it via conda, but it still says: 'module' object has no attribute 'Chart'

Comment: Did you restart the kernel after installing?